# Why cant i do 48 hours?

Tags: c#, winforms

Im trying to make my label count down 42 hours. This is my code

```
    var end = DateTime.Parse("21:00");
        var now = DateTime.Now;      // Could also be some other point in time
        TimeSpan timeLeft = end - now;
        label1.Text = "" + timeLeft;
```

Comment: since there's no question mark, i assume the question is "This is my code".....and yes, this is your code. You're welcome.

Comment: `var end = DateTime.Now.AddHours(48)`?

Comment: `label1.Text = $"{DateTime.Now.AddHours(48):dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm}";` we add `48` hours and represent new time in desired format, if I've understood you right

Comment: @MLeblanc its kinda in the title... I cant make it do 48 hours since it says System.FormatException: 'The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.'

Answer (score 1):

Your end variable is assigned by parsing a string which only contains the hour and minute. According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=netcore-3.1#StringToParse):

> A string with a time but no date component. The method assumes the
> current date unless you call the Parse(String, IFormatProvider,
> DateTimeStyles) overload and include
> DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault in the styles argument, in which
> case the method assumes a date of January 1, 0001.

So 21:00 is converted to 9 PM on the current date of your local computer's timezone.

Any time on the current date can not (by definition of a day) exceed 23:59 from "Now". If you are newing up a date, you can pass in the full DateTime in the constructor, either as individual values or as an ISO8601 string. For example:

```
var a = new DateTime(2020, 8, 20, 9, 0, 0);
var b = new DateTime("2020-08-20 09:00:00");
```

The second thing that I will throw out there, is that you (almost certainly) should not be calculating the difference based on the local time. Even if you are fortunate enough to be able to assume the same timezone applies to both, this (like a lot of other DateTime math) will give you the wrong answer if you cross a Daylight Savings boundary. Rather, convert both start and end to UTC and do the subtraction with UTC.

Finally, you probably want to check out the [docs on TimeSpan.ToString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tostring?view=netcore-3.1) to make sure your label text renders the timespan the way you are hoping. (It isn't going to show "48" by default even if you did have the right dates).